# Angular SVG Path Not Visible

Tags: javascript, angular, svg

I am working on a project where I have a page that lists job positions and I need to visually show progression (how to get from one job to another) using lines/arrows so the user can follow along. I created a page that contains all the data for this and now I am trying to use SVG paths to create lines on top of the data and draw paths.

I found some code in another answer that I converted to pure JS and removed the jQuery references to be able to use it in my project.

**Here is the working fiddle with one path example:**

http://jsfiddle.net/x4nmqkLj/

**Here is my attempt:**

http://jsfiddle.net/szrdb263/

My issue that I am facing is that the SVG and Path appear to be created BUT, I am unable to see the line/path on the DOM. However if I view the elements in the web tools, I can see the SVG element and path element and they appear to be in the correct location to where the path would be drawn from the starting and ending position.

**My rendered path is as follows:**

```
<path class="path" id="path1" d="M449.953125 512.34375 V568.03125 A55.6875 55.6875 0 0 0 505.640625 623.71875 H765.515625 A55.6875 55.6875 0 0 1 821.203125 679.40625 V1055.3203125"></path>
```

**Here is the SVG Element:**
[image]

**Here is the Path Element:**
[image]

The path should be drawing a line from the first box `1A` to the bottom row, second box `2D`. The path appears to be where its expected, the bottom center of the first box to the top center of the bottom box where the arrow would be drawn.

**CSS:**

```
  #svgContainer {
    z-index: -10;
    opacity: 0.5;
    margin: 2.5em 2.5em;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #999;
}

  path { 
    fill:   none !important;
    stroke: #000 !important;
    stroke-width: 0.7em !important;
  }
```

Is anything angular specific that I am missing causing this to not show up?

I am not terribly familiar with SVG but seeing both the SVG element and Path element in the DOM makes me think its pretty close. I can't imagine the arrow is outside of the DOM anywhere but I may be wrong.

**Update:**

I pasted my path code in a few "validator" sites for SVG to see if it would draw it and I am not getting any visual indication. This would suggest that there is something wrong with the coordinates that it is using to create the path. However, the same code is being used on the working example so I am wondering if this is an angular quirk after all with manipulating the DOM of sorts.

**Update 2:**
I believe I have solved the issue. I had to change how I was getting the ending coordinates in the JS.

**Before:**

```
  // calculate path's end (x,y) coords
  var endX = endCoord.offsetLeft + 0.5 * endElem.offsetWidth - svgLeft;
  var endY = endCoord.offsetTop - svgTop;
```

**After:**

```
  // calculate path's end (x,y) coords
  var endX = endCoord.getBoundingClientRect().left + 0.5 * endElem.offsetWidth - svgLeft;
  var endY = endCoord.getBoundingClientRect().top - svgTop;
```

**New Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8dumowvt/

Comment: The `<svg>` element has a `height` attribute of 0. Increasing the height causes it to appear. The `#svgContainer` element has a z-index of -10, which is drawing it behind the other elements.

Comment: @AlexK I will look at that now. The JS is supposed to be calculating the height and width values based on the coordinates of the elements and adjusting the values accordingly.

Comment: I've rolled back the question to the point it was at when it was answered so that the answer makes sense. If there are more issues, it's best to ask another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your example working by doing the following:

- Replaced `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` by `getBoundingClientRect().top` and `getBoundingClientRect().left` in `connectElements()`
- Adjusted style of svgContainer to give it a positive z-index, so that the svg is drawn over the other elements
- Added `pointer-events: none;` to the svgContainer so that you can still interact with the elements behind it

Here's the updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLhdr6c7/).

Comment: Seems like offsetTop was returning 0, which caused the svg to have a calculated height of 0.

Comment: Thanks, will accept this now. Any thoughts on the updated question (New Issue)? Simply trying to add the paths dynamically and its doing something strange..

Comment: Do you specify `path { fill: none; }` somewhere in your CSS?

Comment: Yep, hadn't changed anything from the original working one we had other than removing the hardcoded path in favor of dynamically adding it.

Comment: Got it :/ - Must be an angular thing. Since it was adding the element dynamically, it wasn't obeying the styling in the component that it was generating this from. I moved the `path` css to the global stylesheet and it seems to work fine.